# Define a function to latex italicize (or boldface) a word selection in Emacs

Tags: emacs, latex, org-mode

I use Emacs' org-mode to take notes in class, which I then export in latex. I found org-mode's default markers for bold and italic (`*` and `/` respectively) quite useful, but I had to stop using them to avoid confusing the org exporter. I would like to have a function to italicize a word selection. In other words, the function should append `\textit{` and `}` respectively to the beginning and to the end of a selection.

Org has a function, defined in org.el, that does this, called `org-emphasize` (the code is posted below), but it is constructed to work only with the org markers. Unfortunately, I am not very proficient in elisp to modify it to do what I want.

Any suggestions on how to go about building my desired function, would be greatly appreciated. Thank you, all!

```
(defun org-emphasize (&optional char)
"Insert or change an emphasis, i.e. a font like bold or italic.
If there is an active region, change that region to a new emphasis.
If there is no region, just insert the marker characters and position
the cursor between them.
CHAR should be the marker character.  If it is a space, it means to
remove the emphasis of the selected region.
If CHAR is not given (for example in an interactive call) it will be
prompted for."
 (interactive)
(let ((erc org-emphasis-regexp-components)
 (string "") beg end move s)
 (if (org-region-active-p)
 (setq beg (region-beginning)
      end (region-end)
      string (buffer-substring beg end))
  (setq move t))

(unless char
  (message "Emphasis marker or tag: [%s]"
       (mapconcat #'car org-emphasis-alist ""))
  (setq char (read-char-exclusive)))
(if (equal char ?\s)
(setq s ""
      move nil)
  (unless (assoc (char-to-string char) org-emphasis-alist)
(user-error "No such emphasis marker: \"%c\"" char))
  (setq s (char-to-string char)))
(while (and (> (length string) 1)
    (equal (substring string 0 1) (substring string -1))
    (assoc (substring string 0 1) org-emphasis-alist))
  (setq string (substring string 1 -1)))
(setq string (concat s string s))
(when beg (delete-region beg end))
(unless (or (bolp)
    (string-match (concat "[" (nth 0 erc) "\n]")
              (char-to-string (char-before (point)))))
  (insert " "))
(unless (or (eobp)
    (string-match (concat "[" (nth 1 erc) "\n]")
              (char-to-string (char-after (point)))))
  (insert " ") (backward-char 1))
(insert string)
(and move (backward-char 1))))
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if it worth defining a new lisp function. This is mainly a LaTeX problem as described here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/258394/make-block-of-text-italicized

You can transpose this solution to Org as follow. First, observe how Org special blocks:

```
#+BEGIN_mySpecialBlock
 ...
#+END_mySpecialBlock
```

are exported to LaTeX

```
\begin{mySpecialBlock}
 ...
\end{mySpecialBlock}
```

(see [Org doc Special-blocks-in-LaTeX-export](https://orgmode.org/manual/Special-blocks-in-LaTeX-export.html#Special-blocks-in-LaTeX-export) for further details)

Then define new LaTeX environments as:

```
#+LATEX_HEADER: \newenvironment{itquote} {\begin{quote}\itshape} {\end{quote}\ignorespacesafterend}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \newenvironment{itpars}  {\par\itshape} {\par}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \newenvironment{bfquote} {\begin{quote}\bfseries} {\end{quote}\ignorespacesafterend}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \newenvironment{bfpars}  {\par\bfseries} {\par}
```

The [lipsum](https://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum?lang=en) LaTeX package is used to generate some dummy text.

```
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{lipsum}
```

You can test the approach with this Org document

```
#+LATEX: \lipsum[66]

#+BEGIN_bfquote
#+LATEX: \lipsum[66]
#+END_bfquote

#+BEGIN_bfpars
#+LATEX: \lipsum[66]
#+END_bfpars

#+BEGIN_itquote
#+LATEX: \lipsum[66]
#+END_itquote

#+BEGIN_itpars
#+LATEX: \lipsum[66]
#+END_itpars
```

After LaTeX export, `C-c C-e l o`, you will get something like:
[image]

---

For a better clarity here is the complete Org document. For a real document remove all references to `lipsum` which is only the text generator.

```
#+LATEX_HEADER: \newenvironment{itquote} {\begin{quote}\itshape} {\end{quote}\ignorespacesafterend}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \newenvironment{itpars}  {\par\itshape} {\par}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \newenvironment{bfquote} {\begin{quote}\bfseries} {\end{quote}\ignorespacesafterend}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \newenvironment{bfpars}  {\par\bfseries} {\par}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{lipsum}

#+TITLE: My Title

* My section

#+LATEX: \lipsum[66]

#+BEGIN_bfquote
#+LATEX: \lipsum[66]
#+END_bfquote

#+BEGIN_bfpars
#+LATEX: \lipsum[66]
#+END_bfpars

#+BEGIN_itquote
#+LATEX: \lipsum[66]
#+END_itquote

#+BEGIN_itpars
#+LATEX: \lipsum[66]
#+END_itpars
```